# Create a list of random even numbers in a specified range using only randint

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

I'm trying to create a random list with numbers from 0 to 10,000 (inclusive). I need to get a list with even numbers only.

This is my code:

```
from random import randint

def test(mini, maxx, quantity):
    myl = [randint(mini, maxx) * 2 for i in range(quantity)]
    return myl

print(test(0, 10000, 4))
```

If I try that, I go past the range of 10000 (because the `* 2`).

Also, I can only use the `randint` function.

How do I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5):

Generate random numbers from 0 to 5000 and multiply by 2. You have to operate over the correct range if you want to ensure proper results, and include the fact that your bounds are both inclusive:

```
def test(start, stop, n):
    start, stop = min(start, stop), max(start, stop)
    realmax = (stop - start + 2) // 2 - 1   # Range from zero, inclusive
    realstart = start + (start % 2)         # Offset to ensure even result
    return [randint(0, realmax) * 2 + realstart for _ in range(n)]
```

In case you are wondering where `(stop - start + 2) // 2 - 1` comes from.

- `stop - start + 1` is the size of your inclusive range.
- Another `+ 1` is necessary to make `// 2` act as a ceil-divide instead of a floor-divide. Taking the range 12-14 as an example, you would want to generate two options, not one.
- `// 2` just halves the range, but keeps it an integer.
- The final `- 1` converts a range size into a range boundary, since `randint` is inclusive and we are starting from zero.

Comment: It's a shame that `randint` is a constraint as `return random.choices(range(start, stop+1, 2), k=n)` is nice and elegant.

Comment: @JonClements. Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code -

```
import random
>>> lst = []
>>> def evenrandom(lst):
    for i in range(10):       #assuming we need 10 random numbers
        num = random.randint(1,10000)       #note: I have started from 1 
                                            #with intention
        if num % 2 == 0:
            lst.append(num)
        else:
            lst.append(num -1)
    return lst

>>> print(evenrandom(lst))
[6932, 1690, 5526, 1282, 8332, 2024, 8600, 9500, 1264, 4350]
```

Comment: The `if` can be rephrased as `lst.append(num - num%2)`. That being said, you should start from zero, otherwise the probability of getting zero will be less than all the other numbers in your range.

Answer (score -1):

```
def test(mini,maxx,quantity):
    myl = [randint(mini,int(maxx/2)) * 2 for i in range(quantity)]
    return myl
```

Comment: What if you put in `mini=12, maxx=14`?

Comment: obviously, don't do that:) You should check the input validity elsewhere.

Comment: 12, 14 is a totally valid input. My point is that your function assumes that mini is going to be zero, which it's generally not, or it wouldn't be an input.